# Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s) entity framework core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code

```
 try
    {
        using (var context = await PrepareDatabase())
        {
            // Update temp roles by removing one row, this should affect that RemoveOldRoles below is removing rows from the Role-table
            var entity = context.TempRawRoles.Where(x => x.Account == "brkar4").FirstOrDefault();
            context.TempRawRoles.Remove(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            await CleanUp(context);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Here is my CleanUp

```
   private async Task CleanUp(SecurityContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get only the global ids that belongs to our test accounts
                List<Guid> ids = await GetCreatedTestGlobalIds(context);

                List<IdentityEntity> identities = await context.Identities.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.GlobalId)).ToListAsync();

                context.Identities.RemoveRange(identities);

                await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Throws error

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When `await context.SaveChangesAsync();` is executed in my CleanUp, I get the following error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
>   row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
>   loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for
>   information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency
>   exceptions.

I guess it has something todo with this: `context.TempRawRoles.Remove(entity);`

But how can I fix this?

Comment: You do expect to get 1 result, but you call `FirstOrDefault()`. That function could return NULL if none found. Consider using `Single()`, or `First()` or `if (entity == null) return "Account not found";`

Comment: @bradbury9: in this case, I know that it will return a row, and not null.

Comment: "_it will return a row, and not null_". Then change that and use `Single()` to make sure the behavior is the expected. Now on topic... Could `GetCreatedTestGlobalIds` alter the data?

Comment: @bradbury9: No, it just selects data from the database. A simple select querty

Comment: I noticed this because Rico Wang is necromancing an old post.  Q: If you resolved the problem, please add a response and tell us how :)  Otherwise, please 1) set a breakpoint at `context.Identities.RemoveRange(identities)`, 2) Look at how many elements are in "identities", 3) step through to `context.SaveChangesAsync()` and confirm the error still occurs in this particular test, 4) [Edit] your question and tell us what you found.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private async Task CleanUp(SecurityContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get only the global ids that belongs to our test accounts
            List<Guid> ids = await GetCreatedTestGlobalIds(context);

            List<IdentityEntity> identities = await context.Identities.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.GlobalId)).ToListAsync();

            await context.Identities.RemoveRangeAsync(identities); // modify here

            await context.SaveChangesAsync(); 

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Q: Would you mind adding a bit of explanation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).